# The expectation given in the \"Expect\" request header () could not be fulfilled

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, alamofire

This is my block of code and I am constantly getting the error  errorDomain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." While I tried responseString instead of responseJSON I got the error "The expectation given in the  \"Expect\" request header () could not be fulfilled"

```
let parameter = ["mobileNumber":number]
let header = ["accessToken" : newToken,"Content-Type":"Application/JSON"]
let url1 = NSURL(string: baseUrl + registerMobileUrl)
Alamofire
.request(.POST, url1!, parameters: parameter, encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON, headers : header)
.responseString { response in
print("All header fields are (response.response?.allHeaderFields)")
print("the response main of register mobile is (response)")
```

Comment: So I think the problem is because of the Expect Header 100 continue header. Does anyone have idea about how we can disable it in iOS?

Comment: `100 Continue` is an inherent part of HTTP, you can't disable it if you are not running on HTTP 1.0

Comment: How can I switch to HTTP 1.0 ? Can u suggest me any other solution for my problem above?

Comment: The problem is either in your server implementation or in the Alamofire library.

Comment: Problem in the library like? I dont get it. I have been trying to fix it since hours :(